# Python/Webdriver: how do I add browser binaries to path when I do not have admin rights?

Tags: python, path, system

I need to make three exe files visible to Python by placing them in a location where Python can find them. Placing the files in the same folder with the .py file did not solve the problem

I have no admin rights on my laptop and I can not change the PATH (Windows 10 machine) neither can I place files in the folders where the PATH variable points to

what are my options to trick Python to find the files ?

Comment: You shouldn't explicitly need to add them to path; you can add the location to the driver constructor i.e.

`driver = ChromeDriver("C:\\location\\chromedriver.exe")`

so you can in theory put them anywhere you have permission.

Comment: Thanks I am just starting with this and I did not start reading the docs yet, i was just reading the installation instructions from Git  Your answer put me on the right path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your answer above it looks like you've mixed up 2 solutions;

Solution 1:

```
chromedriver = "C:\\Utils\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
```

Solution 2:

```
chromedriver = "C:\\Utils\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe"

os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
```

In your solution you've called the constructor for the driver twice.

Solution 1 will create the driver based on the executable location you explicitly provided in the constructor.

Solution 2 will create the driver based on the environment variable for the executable.

In your answer what will happen is you'll create 2 instances of Chrome, both are valid and won't throw an error, but it'll just be messy. You should really only call the driver constructor once.

Comment: You are right ..it was just a copy and paste without thinking or reading too much . I just wanted to make sure the idea works. I should

Comment: that explains why I got two browser windows. Is is possible to use this headless? I am looking for a way to replace Mechanize which I need to use with a JavaScript website and Mechanize does not support that

Comment: I think you can use the PhantomJS web driver to do headless testing, but I've not tried it personally

Answer (score 1):

OK this did the trick

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os

chromedriver = "C:\\Utils\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe"

os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
```

Comment: That's not entirely correct, the environment variable part is correct but you shouldn't need to call the Chrome constructor twice; you've mixed up 2 solutions. I'll put my notes in an answer so it's easier.